# Need to apply a style for getting rid of bottom line on Entry

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, multiplatform

First off, I'm brand new to Xamarin Forms so be gentle. I'm needing to get rid of the bottom line that shows for Entry input in Android. It displays fine in iOS. I've done some research and found that this:

```
<style name="NoBaseline" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">#D3D3D3</item>
</style>
```

should do the trick by simply just making the underline the same color as the background color of the Entry box. I've placed this code in my styles.xml file, but I feel like I need to *apply* this style *somewhere*, but I'm just not sure where. Any help for a newb would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the whole file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base"
           parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoBaseline" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">#D3D3D3</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" 
           parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" 
           parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please, post your whole styles.xml code, so we can see if you did it right. The default style is automatically setted by the project template for xamarin forms on visual studio.

Comment: ok i posted the whole file

Comment: So did I do something wrong???

Comment: No everything is alright. I'm searching if can put it inside the `MyTheme` definition, but I agree with @cvanbeek that the custom renderer is a simpler approach

Comment: Right, I've been trying to tackle that myself. with this -> <item name="android:background">@style/NoBaseline</item> added inside of the MyTheme.Base style, but I'm getting an error on load "error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout"

Comment: This way is really wrong. Once the `NoBaseline` is inherited from `Widget.EditText`. I guess you should add the whole `NoBaseline` style declaration in a separated file... [Take a look here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you didn't see this while you were researching, [here is a solution](https://gist.github.com/dkudelko/42f2d5bc1c8b3aba1d3d) posted to Github by dkudelko which is probably a little simpler if you are just trying to remove the underline.

To do this simply create a class in you Android project called NoUnderlineEntry then add this code.

```
using <YourApp>.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;    

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(NoUnderlineEntry))]
namespace <YourApp>.Droid
{
    public class NoUnderlineEntry : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control?.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

After you replace  with the name of your app, you will have created a custom renderer that overrides the default `Entry` on Android to set the control background color to transparent.

[Here is documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/) for creating custom renderers for `Entry`.

**Note: I haven't personally tested it, but multiple people commented that it works.

Comment: I'm on multiplatform though, not Xamarin.Android so at the very least the using directives don't work and neither does ExportRenderer. I've tried this, but don't know how to adapt it to my solution.

Comment: If you look at the solution explorer in VS, do you have multiple different projects?  Usually in Xamarin.Forms, there is a Portable Class Library (PCL) which is where all your shared code goes (pages, api calls, etc.), and then individual platform projects (App.Droid, App.iOS, etc.).  Do you have these different projects in your solution?

Comment: yes i do. my login page is in the shared part and my styles.xml is in the .Droid part

Comment: Make sure you're adding `NoUnderlineEntry` to the .Droid part.  There may be other using statements you need to add if intelisense is showing an error and suggesting them.

Comment: Beautiful. It works. Thank you so much. I guess I was just trying to put that into my shared project folder and that's why it wasn't working before. Really appreciated.

Comment: No problem, glad I can help!